# How to count unique csv/parquet rows?

Tags: java, csv, kotlin, parquet

Is there a better *algorithm* for counting unique rows in csv/parquet than writing to HashMap or reading one row and iterating through whole file(if file is big)?

Comment: In my eyes, you have two only two general options: either you read the hole content at one and using regeular expression to count line breaks or apply the split() method on them, or you read the file partically and iterate through the packages.

Comment: What do you mean with "unique rows"?

Comment: `better algorithm`. Better than what algorithm? Better in what way? Memory? CPU usage? Time it takes?

Comment: @Alex.T Better in anything. I think it's all possible algorithms. Does other algorithms that better than these in anything exist?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to count unique lines in a csv file, you could use Java NIO and streams:

```
Files.lines(Path.of("/path/to/file.csv"))
        .skip(1) // CSV Header
        .distinct()
        .count();
```

This way, the size of the file should not be a problem, since streams process data lazily, so the entire file is never fully loaded into memory.

Comment: I'm almost ensure that count(like terminating operation) read all lines in memory, because I can't understood how can be possible count unique rows without knowing about other rows.

Comment: It can, because streams are processed lazily. After the `distinct()` operation, only unique rows are left, and the `count()` operation (most likely) discards any row it has already counted because it knows it is a terminal operation, so no further processing is possible. The `distinct()` operation still has to keep track of the unique rows, but it can be at most the total number of rows that are unique. But if you do it yourself, you still have to keep track of the uniquenesses via the mentioned `HashMap`, so there is no difference if you do it manually. The big benifit here is lazy processing